# I'm getting an error in React-Native, Unable to resolve module `./http://localhost:8081/index` from ``?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Error: Unable to resolve module `./http://localhost:8081/index` from ``:

None of these files exist:

- http:/localhost:8081/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- http:/localhost:8081/index/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/zodiac0606/Projects/Contacts/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
  at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/home/zodiac0606/Projects/Contacts/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/zodiac0606/Projects/Contacts/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
  at /home/zodiac0606/Projects/Contacts/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42
  at Server. (/home/zodiac0606/Projects/Contacts/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:841:41)
  at Generator.next ()
  at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/zodiac0606/Projects/Contacts/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:99:24)
  at _next (/home/zodiac0606/Projects/Contacts/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:119:9)

I have already tried deleting my node_modules and installing it again. I tried npm start --reset-cache, then run command npx react-native run-android(not working). I am using latest version of react-native(0.62.2).

Is there any other solution ?

Comment: Did you deleted your package-lock.json file ?

Comment: where have you imported this http:/localhost:8081/index(

Comment: No, I didn't delete package-lock.json file

Comment: @GauravRoy I don't know how react-native runs in background. As I'm new to this I just followed the docs and Its been 2 weeks it was running perfectly. But now this error is showing.

Comment: Now myApp is running in debug mode meaning while its connected to the system via usb but when I build a release apk using android-studio its not working as I installed it on my phone its closing it as I open the app.

Comment: You question is not clear, you are trying to run in android studio, and when you try to run you get the above error ? Is it

Comment: No, I'm not trying to run in android-studio. I'm just running it through terminal with via npm start cause it's a react-native project and by installing and running on android by npx react-native run-android

Comment: It solved it self just had to update react-native they released a new version in th epast 2 days. Thanks guys

Comment: are you using sentry? We just stumbled upon the same issue, and for us, it seems that sentry is the trouble maker.